# Center a textarea and place a button at its right, vertically centered

Tags: html, css, button, textarea

I would like to :

1. center align the textarea horizontally and stay centered all the time
2. place the button 15px at the right of the textarea and stay there
3. center the button vertically to the textarea

Thank you for your help

```css
        #title {
                background-color: darkblue; 
                 font-size:40px;
               font-weight:bold;
                color:white;
               margin:0;  
                padding:2px;
                text-align:center;
                height:60px;
                width:100%x;
            }
      
         #myForm {
                margin-top:30px;
                z-index: -1;
                text-align: center;
                height:80px;
            }
            
            #name {
               width: 300px;
               height:50px;
               font-size: 26px;
               line-height:20px;
               color:black;
               border-style: solid;
               border-width: 2.5px;
               border-color:black;
               padding-left:5px;
         padding-top:12px;
            }

            
       #end {
         
                font-size:18px;
                margin-left:20px;  
       }
```

```html
<p id= "title">Centered title</p> 
<form  id="myForm" action="" method="post">
<textarea id="name"  name="nom"> </textarea>
<button id="end">end</button>           
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this (Just using vertical-align with display):

```css
#title {
  background-color: darkblue;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%x;
}

#myForm {
  margin-top: 30px;
  z-index: -1;
  text-align: center;
  height: 80px;
}

#name {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2.5px;
  border-color: black;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 80px;
}

#end {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<p id="title">Centered title</p>


<form id="myForm" action="" method="post">
  <textarea id="name" name="nom" placeholder="name" autofocus></textarea>
  <button id="end" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md">end</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I think you missed something. The textarea **only** should be centered (see Pt.1 of the question). Then the button has to sit to tehe right.

Comment: @Paulie_D Just give a margin-left to textarea...y already done, see again the the demo

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox (or any other usual non-positional centering method) can get you close but this will center the *combined* textarea/button.

Demo showing the issue...

```css
#title {
  background-color: darkblue;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%x;
}
#myForm {
  margin-top: 30px;
  z-index: -1;
  text-align: center;
  height: 80px;
}
#name {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2.5px;
  border-color: black;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 12px;
}
#end {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#myForm {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<p id="title">Centered title</p>


<form id="myForm" action="" method="post">
  <textarea id="name" name="nom" placeholder="name" autofocus></textarea>
  <button id="end" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md">end</button>
</form>
```

Unfortunately, to center the `textarea` and have the button on it's right we need to use absolute positioning.

```css
#title {
  background-color: darkblue;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%x;
}
#myForm {
  margin-top: 30px;
  z-index: -1;
  text-align: center;
  height: 80px;
}
#name {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2.5px;
  border-color: black;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 12px;
}
#end {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#myForm {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
#end {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translatey(-50%);
  left: calc(50%+150px);
}
```

```html
<p id="title">Centered title</p>


<form id="myForm" action="" method="post">
  <textarea id="name" name="nom" placeholder="name" autofocus></textarea>
  <button id="end" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md">end</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code

```
#myForm {
margin-top: 30px;
z-index: -1;
text-align: center;
height: 80px;
display: -ms-flex;
-ms-align-items: center;
-ms-justify-content: center;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
```

Note: This will work fine greater than ie10. Except this no other changes required.

Comment: Unfortunately I think you missed something. The textarea **only** should be centered (see Pt.1 of the question). Then the button has to sit to tehe right.

Comment: @Paulie_D. I think it doesn't matter whatever the width of the parent container, According to my solution textarea will be centered and button will float to its right. Check https://jsfiddle.net/wtbweehw/20/

Comment: No, you are centering **both** of the elements...not just the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the `textarea` in the provided example has a fixed `width` (300px), you can achieve this with a little bit of trickery involving relative positioning, like so:

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;font-family:sans-serif;margin:0;padding:0;}
textarea,button{
  display:inline-block;
  margin:20px 0;
  position:relative;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
textarea{
  left:calc(50% - 150px);
  width:300px;
}
button{
  left:calc(50% - 135px);
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea><button>button</button>
```